# Is it possible to let webpack bundle CSS without import css in my entry js?

Tags: css, webpack, browserify

Importing CSS file in js is webpack-specific. If I use `gulp+browserify` I will need `browserify-css`. I feel uncomfortable with writing source code that directly depends on having browserify-css or webpack(especially I am not writing React/Vue app, just vanilla js).

I find some Q&A related to this, e.g. [import CSS and JS files using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015521/import-css-and-js-files-using-webpack) and [Can I build sass/less/css in webpack without requiring them in my JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780585/can-i-build-sass-less-css-in-webpack-without-requiring-them-in-my-js)

They suggested multiple-entry-points config (if I understand them correctly), i.e. create a dummy js file with only `import css` and add another entry in webpack.config.js for that js so the real entry js does not need to `import css`

I tried it but I still don't like the solution. Is there any other solution? If someone can confirm there is none I will be satisfied too. B/C someone else raised the same issue against [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/552) and a reply said

> webpack natively only understands 'js-ish' files and using a
>   'css-ish' file as an entry point isn't recommended (imho it should
>   even fail),so you will get a dummy bundle per css entry to 'handle'
>   that. require/import the css inside an entrypoint

Answer (score 10):

I asked the same question at https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack and no reply either I have almost gave up then I found it was answered here  [Webpack extract text plugin outputting .js and .css file for styles entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480470/webpack-extract-text-plugin-outputting-js-and-css-file-for-styles-entry/) and [Can I use webpack to generate CSS and JS separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322958/can-i-use-webpack-to-generate-css-and-js-separately) here.

So setting webpack.config.js like this webpack will output `index.js & index.css`

I don't need to import css in `index.js` any more!

```
entry:{
  index: [
    './src/js/index.js',
    "./resources/css/index.scss"
  ]
},
output:{
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
},
```

Comment: This worked for me when everything is handled within the bundle.js.
But it doesn't work in the case where a function from bundle.js needs to be exposed to an external calling .html file
see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673922/how-to-configure-webpack-to-automatically-detect-changes-in-css-file-and-also)