# How to configure webpack to automatically detect changes in .css file, and also export internal bundle.js function

Tags: webpack

I use webpack to transpile the code.
I have the following requirements:

- requirement1 - webpack needs to detect changes in the .css, .js files (without importing the .css file from the .js file) and automatically rebuild
- requirement2 - An outer .html file should call an internal bundle.js function

I can achieve each of the requirements separately but not together.
**What should to achieve these requirements at the same time?**

Thanks

---

Setting for requirement1:
To achieve requirement1 I followed the instructions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807092/is-it-possible-to-let-webpack-bundle-css-without-import-css-in-my-entry-js)
With this setting:

- If I change the .css file, webpack automatically rebuilds the code
- But I can not access a function in bundle.js from an external .html

The webpack config file:

```
cat ~/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webpack/webpack.config.js
...
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('js/dir1/'),

    // option1 - webback detects changes in the .css file, 
    //           but an internal bundle.js function can be called from the outside via e.g. lib1.func1()
    entry:{
        index: [
            './main.js',
            "../../css/style.css"
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/lib'),
        publicPath: 'build',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: "lib1",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
    },
...
```

---

Setting for requirement2:
To achieve requirement2 I followed the instructions in [here](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/write-a-javascript-library-using-webpack-and-babel/)

With this setting:

- I can access a function in bundle.js from an external .html
- But if I change the .css file, webpack does not automatically rebuild.

The webpack config file:

```
cat ~/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webpack/webpack.config.js
...
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('js/dir1/'),

    // option2 - webback does not detect changes in the .css file
    //           but an internal bundle.js function can be called from the outside via e.g. lib1.func1()
    entry: './main.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/lib'),
        publicPath: 'build',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: "lib1",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/multiple-entries-e1b3d83579bf) tutorial to create multiple entries (it creates an unused bundle file: `css.bundle.js`)

With the following setting (option3), I can achieve the 2 requirements together.
(note the changes to the `entry`, and `output.filename` fields).

```
cat ~/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webpack/webpack.config.js
...
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('js/dir1/'),


    // option3 - webback detects changes in the .css file, and
    //           an internal bundle.js function can be called from the outside via e.g. lib1.func1()
    entry: {
        app: './main.js',
        css: "../../css/style.css"
    },
    
    output: {
        // the output file bundle.js is placed in the path "build/dir1/"
        path: path.resolve('build/dir1'),
        publicPath: 'build',
        filename: "./[name].bundle.js" ,
        library: "lib1",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
    },
```